# wordpress css editor doesn't work

Tags: html, css, wordpress

some part of my css code written in wordpress editor dedicated for mobile version of a website does not work and it doesn't appear in inspect page dedicated

i would like for my table to have horizontal scroll when used by mobile phone

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {

.gem-textbox-content {
padding-right: 30px !important;
}

.vc_tta.vc_general.vc_tta-accordion .vc_tta-panel-body {
padding: 25px;
}

/*form here forward code doesn't word*/ 
.gem-table .gem-table-responsive .gem-table-style-1 .row-headers {
    display: block !important;
    overflow-x: scroll !important;
}

.tabletolist .rh .nrh {
    display:none !important;
}

table {
display:block !important;
}

}
```

and when i write this code directly in dev console it works, but when i write it in wp css editor it doesnt, i put !important to overwrite inline css

Answer (score 0):

You should change the version number in your enqueue code (usually in functions.php for themes) so that the style sheet is reloaded.

```
    wp_enqueue_style( 'my_styles', plugins_url( 'mystyles.css' , dirname(__FILE__) ), array(), 5.52);
```

In the above example, I would change 5.52 to 5.53 to trigger a style change.

```
    wp_enqueue_style( 'my_styles', plugins_url( 'mystyles.css' , dirname(__FILE__) ), array(), 5.53);
```